# error ConnectorError: connector "strapi-hook-mongoose" not found: Cannot find module 'strapi-connector-strapi-hook-mongoose'

Tags: mongoose, strapi

I got this error in strapi and had to jump through a few hoops to solve it. If you're getting this error there's nothing wrong with your mongoose configuration. I'm using node 10.15.3 and npm 6.4.1 and Strapi 3.0.0-beta.18.3 https://github.com/strapi/strapi/releases/tag/v3.0.0-beta.18.3

Answer (score 0):

Please see the migration guide as it explains what you need to do: https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/migration-guide/migration-guide-beta.17-to-beta.18.html#upgrading-your-dependencies

`"strapi-connector-mongoose": "3.0.0-beta.18.3",`

Answer (score -1):

The problems I encountered were with the Strapi codebase. 
The first issue was with Strapi reading two of the enumerations I had in my models file.
In my `/api/artists/models/Artists.settings.json` file I had the following

```
"genres_new": {
  "enum": [
    "hip hop",
    "r&b",
    "pop",
"dance"
  ],
  "type": "enumeration"
},"
```

I had to remove the `&` from `r & b` and make it `r and b`

```
"genres_new": {
  "enum": [
    "hip hop",
    "r and b",
    "pop",
"dance"
  ],
  "type": "enumeration"
},"
```

I also had an enumeration with a series of integers from 1..10 which I had to remove completely.

After making these changes I upgraded to v3.0.0-beta.18.3 by doing the following:

1. Update your package.json dependencies

   ```
       "strapi": "3.0.0-beta.18.3",
       "strapi-admin": "3.0.0-beta.18.3",
       "strapi-connector-mongoose": "3.0.0-beta.18.3",
       "strapi-plugin-content-manager": "3.0.0-beta.18.3",
       "strapi-plugin-content-type-builder": "3.0.0-beta.18.3",
       "strapi-plugin-email": "3.0.0-beta.18.3",
       "strapi-plugin-graphql": "3.0.0-beta.18.3",
       "strapi-plugin-upload": "3.0.0-beta.18.3",
       "strapi-plugin-users-permissions": "^3.0.0-next.41",
       "strapi-utils": "3.0.0-beta.18.3"
     }
   ```
2. Update the modules, clear your cache and build directories

```
     npm install strapi-connector-strapi-hook-mongoose 
     npm install -g install-peerdeps
     npm install
     npm audit fix
     rm -rf .cache
     rm -rf build
     npm run dev
```

I then got the following error

```
error TypeError: fn is not a function
    at execBootstrap (.../src/node_modules/strapi/lib/Strapi.js:381:15)
    at Strapi.runBootstrapFunctions (.../src/node_modules/strapi/lib/Strapi.js:399:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

I fixed it by following the instructions here [Compile error when starting strapi in development mode #4015](https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/4015)

I was then able to start my Strapi server
`npm run start`